# Inbox Table Like Gmail - Fixed Row Height

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing an angular email app and have used bootstrap tables in my mail template.
The body of the message is large and I would like to limit this to be just a single line, something similar to how gmail does it. Right now, my cell auto sizes which increases the size of the overall row. I used a couple of angular filters to limit the characters but I don't think that's all that Gmail is doing. There is some sort of an overflow hidden applied to the table row and also the height of each row is consistent.

How do I tweak my table css so that the row does not auto size when the cell data is a lot?

My HTML Code : http://pastebin.com/13jd9Efq
I'm using the latest version of bootstrap css.

[image: Screenshot of Gmail Inbox Table]

Comment: You applied for a job at dice, nice. Work on Battlefield 5 with dice and make it spectacular. Anyway, in your css, you could try `position:fixed;` or `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;` and see if that does anything, if not then... soz soz soz

Comment: Ha! Yes I did long time back. Never unsubscribed.
Css on which element?

Comment: You could add to your <table> tag `<table style="position:fixed;">`. I tried your html on jsfiddle, seems normal to me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xGh0stSn1p3r/kNmu8/)

Comment: Ignore what I said above, check the answer I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you'd want `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` styles.  If you want you can also add the `text-overlow: ellipsis` style for a nice effect.  You can use `table-layout: fixed` to ignore the size of the contents of the cells and only look at the heading sizes, otherwise automatic column sizing can take into account the full width of the string [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/h7Gq3/):

```
table.special { table-layout: fixed }

table.special th { width: 20% }

table.special th.content { width: 40% }

table.special td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! That worked in Chrome but not in firefox :)
However, table.special th {width:25%} really does nothing. I removed it and it showed the same way. Also, I'm trying to put some cellspacing and padding so I can nicely separate the date column, but it's not working... http://jsfiddle.net/NxU6m/1/.

Comment: Apologies, firefox must not like overflow-x, I replace it with the regular overflow, changed the content column's relative size to show it working and added info on text-overflow: ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

On your `<tr>` tags you should add `style="width:[desired width]"` so they don't resize, example:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">MessageID</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Sender</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Content</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-click="changeRoute('mail',message)" ng-repeat="message in mails.messages | filter:search | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Sender</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
<tr ng-click="changeRoute('mail',message)" ng-repeat="message in mails.messages | filter:search | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Sender</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can change the text of the `<td>` tags and it won't resize. You might want to add a padding to the left on your `<td>` tags so they are more 'inline' with the `<tr>` tag's text. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xGh0stSn1p3r/esn6E/)

Comment: Thanks, but the column still auto-sizes in height. Also I want an overflow hidden on the width which prevents all of my text from showing.
http://jsfiddle.net/esn6E/1/

Comment: Try `overflow:hidden`